# On the tensor product of infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Is there some example of an infinite dimensional vector space over some field $k$, such that:
$$
A\cong A\otimes_k A
$$
Clearly the above cannot be valid for any f.d. vector space, due to a dimensionality argument. But what about the infinite dimensional case ?

Comment: We can also have this if $A$ is zero or one-dimensional.

Comment: Are you working just with $k$-vector spaces or with $k$-algebras? This makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

It's valid for any infinite dimensional $ A $. In general, if $ A $ and $ B $ are vector spaces over $ k $ of dimensions $ n $ and $ m $ respectively, then the tensor product $ A \otimes_k B $ has dimension $ nm $ over $ k $. This remains true even when $ n, m $ are allowed to be *infinite* cardinals, and we have that $ \aleph^2 = \aleph $ for any infinite cardinal $ \aleph $. Since the isomorphism class of a vector space is determined entirely by its dimension, the result follows.